# Angular 9 Create component in a specific folder not in app(default) folder

Tags: module, components, angular9

I have src/app/pages folder and I want to create new components inside of this folder. I have tried this

```
ng g component pages/tasdiq
```

but got this error "More than one module matches. Use skip-import option to skip importing the component into the closest module."

I have app.module.ts and app-routing.module.ts modules(I am editing existing project)

How can I solve it

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answere!

I just had to specify the module too

```
ng g component {folder-name-inside-of-app-folder}\{component-name} --module={existing-module's-name}
```

In my case `ng g component pages\tasdiq --module=app.module`

It worked:)